# How to eliminate polygon boundaries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, grass-gis, vector

I'm working in both ArcMap and Grass

I have a problem with the boundaries or the edges of my vectors. The vectors are a result of object segmentation (called classification) in Grass Gis. In Grass, an images is segmented and then I converted the raster into vector resulting in this: 
[image]

(this has been edited) And this is great however, the vector layer is framed. The 'frame' isn't a separate thing; those lines are polygon boundaries like any other on the interior.
There is a square around the vector layer but because I have a little over thousand object segmentation rasters (which I'll turn into vectors) I need continuation, the frame must go.

[image]

Any thoughts on how to eliminate the frame? I'm open to Grass and ArcMap solutions. Maybe the solution is somewhere earlier in the process (the process being object classification to vector)

Edit:
Here is an example of the intersection of 4 vector layers.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you must use the Dissolve tool, based on a common attribute.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000

Comment: How would I use dissolve? I don't see any common attributes that I could use

Comment: From the example you sent, it seems that you first need to do a bit of editing, not all the geometries fit together along the borders. Then whatever these geometries represent, they should have an attribute that they share (a land cover class, a code, a name..). If not, you should also create this common attribute.

Comment: I think I understand. I guess I'm hoping for a more automatic way of doing this, because I have such a large datasaet

Comment: If you don't have a common attribute to dissolve on then you will need to manually merge the neighbouring polygons one by one.

Comment: @AdamH This process is known as edge-matching. In theory the common attribute would be whatever defines the classes. When you vectorized the classed raster, there *should* be an attribute defining what class it came from. If they're all just polygons with no attributes, you may want to go back to that step. However I should point out a simple dissolve won't eliminate the 'frame' lines completely, as it's obvious from your image that classes aren't consistent from image to image. *Some* seem to match, but many don't (though it's hard to see with them all one color).

Comment: I don't have any common attribute. Each polygon is a unique object representing patch in the landscape. I think the solution is earlier in the process.Or maybe I can overlay the images with a line and use it to delete the frame and then fix with topography tools. But that sounds far reached

Comment: @AdamH Overlaying the image would allow you to see which polys are the same type and should be joined, but that immediately heads down the manual editing route. The 'frame' isn't a separate thing; those lines are polygon boundaries like any other on the interior, arising from unmatched classifications at the edges of adjoining images. Either the classification/images need to be more standardized/common scale, or you will have to do a more extensive edge-matching process. I would definitely go back to vectorization and make sure your polys have an attribute defining what class they belong to.

Comment: Well, I'm still working on this. The polygons or a result of object segmentation, they are not classes, that is why they don't have any common attributes, they are all unique objects. I could however locate all polygons along the frame and perhaps merge them. And yes, the problem is that the frame isn't separate thing (I think I'll add that to the question, I did not word it well) Maybe I'll end up manually connecting the different polygons, hope not though.

Comment: I wonder if http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.to.db.html could help you, it comes with a "sides" method to upload the IDs of left/right side polygons of a common boundary. Also used here: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_length_of_common_boundaries

Comment: I found one solution, in ArcMap. I used a line shapefile that covers the frame. I then used select by location to select all polygons within 200m from that line. I then merged the polygons using edit. This is a satisfying solution, though I would like it to be more automatic to save time. But maybe a solution to that will come later on. But this could be done without the select procedure, that just helps me identifying the polygons.

Comment: @AdamH I'm afraid I don't follow. Selecting all polygons within 200m of the frame and then merging them would eliminate a great number of individual polygons, resulting in some amorphous blob version of the frame (as a grid in the data) rather than lines. This would seem to defeat the purpose of 'unique objects'. I guess I'm having trouble understanding your data and what you're trying to do. It sounds like a landcover classification but you're indicating uniqueness of every polygon. Perhaps more explanation or a screenshot of what you *want* it to look like would help.

Comment: There is no land cover classification involved. I'm analyzing patches in the natural landscape and later on I will count the number of patches within a certain radius. I Will not merge together all the polygons along the frame. I will basically go through all the polygons along the straight lines and merge together those that belong together so that they reflect the patch in the picture. I sort of ended in what you said before, that will be a lot of manual editing.